# How to turn off Automatic Login

Tags: password

I have turned on Automatic Login in Ubuntu 14.04. Now I cant install any updates as I cannot authorize. I tried to turn off Automatic Login, using the User Accounts screen in System Settings. But to make any changes I need to unlock it. When I press the Unlock button I am again asked for an authorization password. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you know your user account password?

Comment: This authentication is set default by Ubuntu!

Comment: Yes, I do. Since I've set it to automatic login it is set to No Password. I have tried the previous password, entering no password and just entering enter. It will not accept either one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using an administrative account. (By which I don't mean root) Then you just enter your password you supplied when you installed Ubuntu.

If you, however, have no administrative account and don't know the root password, you need to ask a person who owns an administrative account to give you the password or to fix this for you.

This whole situation comes up because user and password information is stored in files only root has access to. Thus, these changes can only be accomplished by root or an account which can give root execution rights to a program, in which case an authentication password is asked to prevent abuse. (and sometimes foolishness of users like me)

---

As you disabled your password when enabling autologin, here's the way to reset it:

1. Reboot your computer to GRUB menu (Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot)
2. If 1. doesn't work, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> during boot. Your computer will immediately reboot to GRUB menu.
3. Select the *Recovery Mode* option.
4. Select the *Root shell* entry (I think it's at the bottom). Now Ubuntu will boot into a root terminal.
5. Remount the system as RW: `mount -o rw,remount /`.
6. Set your new password: `passwd yourusername`.
7. Set the root password: `passwd`.
8. Reboot: `reboot`.

Comment: Yes, I am using an administrator account. I am a single user and my root password was the same as my user password until I changed to automatic login.

Comment: This password should still apply. Else you're in trouble... Then try to run `sudo -s` from a terminal and enter your password? Is it accepted?

Comment: I tried sudo -s. It tells me "Sorry, try again"

Comment: Did you disable the password when you enabled auto-login?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly.